# Integration of JBoss Narayana Transaction with Spring Data JPA in Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, spring-data-jpa

From https://github.com/jbosstm/narayana/, I have tried to use

```
org.jboss.narayana.jta:narayana-jta:5.6.2.Final
```

to implement JTA Transaction manager for Spring 
Data JPA (Hibernate) project.

Though Hibernate is successfully returning the object saved with the id(generated by Sequence), the row is **not actually persisted** in the database.

Any help will be more than welcome.

**Spring config:**

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="userTxn" jndi-name="java:comp/UserTransaction" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="tm" jndi-name="java:comp/env/TransactionManager" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jtaTxnSyncRegistry" jndi-name="java:comp/env/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry" />


<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
 <property name="userTransaction" ref="userTxn"></property>
 <property name="transactionManager" ref="tm"/>
 <property name="transactionSynchronizationRegistry" 
  ref="jtaTxnSyncRegistry"/>
</bean>

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


 <bean id="entityManagerFactoryJTA"     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:persistenceUnitName="myPU_JTA">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

 <jpa:repositories base-package="com.xxx.repository.jta"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryJTA"
    transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
```

**context.xml** of **apache-tomcat-8.5.16**:

```
 <Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container"
    type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction" factory="com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager" />

<Transaction    factory="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.UserTransactionImple" />  <!-- auth="Container" -->

<Resource name="TransactionManager" auth="Container" type="javax.transaction.TransactionManager"        factory="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionManagerImple"></Resource>

<Resource name="TransactionSynchronizationRegistry" auth="Container"  type="javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry"
    factory="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryImple" />
```

Answer (score 0):

We had introduced the tomcat-jta module to help integrating with the tomcat since the Narayana 5.5. See https://github.com/jbosstm/narayana/tree/master/tomcat so I think you need to use the following context.xml

```
<!-- Narayana resources -->
<Transaction factory="org.jboss.narayana.tomcat.jta.UserTransactionFactory"/>
<Resource name="TransactionManager" type="javax.transaction.TransactionManager"
          factory="org.jboss.narayana.tomcat.jta.TransactionManagerFactory"/>
<Resource name="TransactionSynchronizationRegistry" type="javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry"
          factory="org.jboss.narayana.tomcat.jta.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryFactory"/>
```

Comment: This module is no more in the master branch. 
I can find it in some tags, like https://github.com/jbosstm/narayana/blob/5.9.0.Final/tomcat/tomcat-jta/.

It looks like it has been moved to https://github.com/web-servers/narayana-tomcat/tree/master/tomcat-jta.